# react redux array nested Tree Menu

Tags: javascript, react-redux, mutation

I'm a learner developer, and I'm build a app with a tree menu(react + redux + sagas), but I'm getting some errors of Mutation State, I saw what best practices is stay de state flat as possible, but I didn't finded one menu tree what work with a flat state, so my data is look this:

```
menuTree: [{
    id: 'id-root',
    name: 'root',
    toggled: true,
    children: [
        {
            id: 'id-parent1',
            name: 'parent1',
            toggled: true,
            children: [
                { 
                  id: '123',
                  name: 'parent1_child1' 
                },
                { 
                  id: '234',
                  name: 'parent1_child2' 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'id-loading-parent',
            name: 'loading parent',
            loading: true,
            children: []
        },
        {
            id: 'id-parent2',
            name: 'parent2',
            toggled: true,
            children: [
                {
                    id: 'parent2_children1',
                    name: 'nested parent2',
                    children: [
                        { 
                          id: '345',
                          name: 'parent2 child 1 nested child 1' 
                        },
                        { 
                          id: '456',
                          name: 'parent2 child 1 nested child 2' 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}],
```

And my redux action:

```
case types.SOLUTION__MENUCURSOR__SET:
  // console.log('action payload', action.payload);
  // console.log('state', state);
  const cursor = action.payload.cursor;
  // console.log('set menu cursor action', cursor);
  return { 
    ...state,
    menuTree: state.menuTree.map(
      function buscaIdMenuTree(currentValue, index, arr){
        if(currentValue.id){
          if(currentValue.id.includes(cursor.id)){
            currentValue.toggled = action.payload.toggled;
            return arr;
          }else{
            if(currentValue.children)
            {
              currentValue.children.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
                return buscaIdMenuTree(currentValue,  index, arr);
              });
            }        
          }
          return arr;
        }
      }
    )[0]
  };
```

The code works but I get Mutation State Error, so someone can help me to fix it ?

Comment: You're modifying `toggled`.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebuild your menu as a plain list:

```
let menuTree = [{
    id: 'id-root',
    name: 'root',
    toggled: true,
    parent: null
},{
    id: 'id-parent1',
    name: 'parent1',
    toggled: true,
    parent: 'id-root'
},{ 
    id: '123',
    name: 'parent1_child1',
    parent: 'id-parent1'
},{ 
    id: '234',
    name: 'parent1_child1',
    parent: 'id-parent1'
},
{
    id: 'id-loading-parent',
    name: 'loading parent',
    loading: true,
    parent: 'id-root'
},{
    id: 'id-parent2',
    name: 'parent2',
    toggled: true,
    parent: 'id-root'
},{
    id: 'parent2_children1',
    name: 'nested parent2',
    parent: 'id-parent2'          
},{ 
    id: '345',
    name: 'parent2 child 1 nested child 1',
    parent: 'parent2_children1'
},
{ 
    id: '456',
    name: 'parent2 child 1 nested child 2',
    parent: 'parent2_children1'
}]
```

then if your menu renderer require a tree you can convert the list to a tree so inside the component renderer `this.menuTree` will be a tree:

```
const buildTree = (tree, cParent = null) => {
  return tree.filter(cNode => cNode.parent == cParent).reduce((curr, next) => {
    let cNode = {...next, children: buildTree(tree, next.id)}
    delete cNode.parent
    return [...curr, cNode]
  }, [])
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    mapTree: builTree(state.mapTree)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Inside the mutation now you just need to create a list of node that needs to be toggled and then map the state accordingly

```
case types.SOLUTION__MENUCURSOR__SET:
  // console.log('action payload', action.payload);
  // console.log('state', state);
  const cursor = action.payload.cursor;
  // console.log('set menu cursor action', cursor);

  const getToggleList = (tree, cursor) => {
    let target = tree.find(cNode => cNode.id == cursor.id)
    if(target.parent != null){
      let parent = tree.find(cNode => cNode.id == target.parent)
      return [target.parent, ...getToggleList(tree, parent)] 
    }else{
     return [] 
    }
  }

  let toggleList = [cursor.id, ...getToggleList(state.menuTree, cursor.id)]

  return { 
    ...state,
    menuTree: state.menuTree.map(node => ({...node, toggle: toggleList.includes(node.id)}))
  };
```

Comment: Hello Vanojx1, thanks a lot, I'll test your sugestion... very thanks!!

Comment: I Think will work, only need to discovery what buildTree problem, it is building wrong:

Comment: I Think will work, only need to discovery what buildTree problem, it is building wrong, It is not neast the children objects, I'll study your bulidTree to discovery what is wrong, very thanks for your sugestion!! The actual result is:  [{id: "id-root", name: "root", toggled: true, parent: null}{id: "id-parent1", name: "parent1", toggled: true, parent: "id-root"}{id: "123", name: "parent1_child1", parent: "id-parent1"}]

You give-me a north now I'll try discover how I neast the children objects.. thanks

Comment: It's work!! Favor, desconsider my coments! your code work perfectly!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, accept the answer if my solution solved your problem